# Not able to install a python module "Pycrypto-2.3"

Tags: python

I tried installing a python module "Pycrypto-2.3".But its giving the following long list of errors:

running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension

/usr/lib/python2.6/pycc -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.6

-c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-i86pc-2.6/src/_fastmath.o

In file included from /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,

from src/_fastmath.c:32:

/usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:969:1: warning: "_FILE_OFFSET_BITS" redefined

In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:37,

from src/_fastmath.c:30:

/usr/include/sys/feature_tests.h:209:1: warning: this is the location of the previous

definition

src/_fastmath.c:34:17: gmp.h: No such file or directory

src/_fastmath.c:39: error: syntax error before "n"

src/_fastmath.c:42: error: syntax error before "m"

The list is long.Though i have followed the correct steps of installation..Can anyone

identify the problem,
Thanks..

Comment: What platform are you building on?

Answer (score 1):

The following error:

```
src/_fastmath.c:34:17: gmp.h: No such file or directory
```

is probably the cause of your problems. It's part of the "gnu multiprecision library", and you need the "dev" part of it. On Debian. the package is libgmp2-dev, for Redhat it's gmp-devel. For other platforms you'll have to search yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that as your on Solaris your going to have to go to the source:

[GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

It has good instructions and support there.