# Not able to install python module pycrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto

I am trying to use a [python module for using Mega](https://github.com/richardasaurus/mega.py) and it requires me to have pycrypto installed. I tried using both pip and easy_install to install it but I have had no luck. With pip I am getting an error like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903863/not-able-to-install-a-python-module-pycrypto-2-3). I followed the link from the answer in that post, but I really have no idea where to go from there. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pycripto is C-based extension. You can compile PyCrypto on Windows, [here is a step-by-step guide](http://yorickdowne.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/compiling-pycrypto-on-win7-64/).

Alternatively, you can install compiled binaries. 
Here is extensive source of compiled python packages for Windows:
[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)