# installing lxml using pip produces an error

Tags: python, lxml, pip, package

I'm following a tutorial for **BeautifulSoup** and I need to use the lxml package

But when i try to install **lxml** using pip it always produces an error at the end 
and therefore **lxml** will not be installed.

This is what I did:

```
pip install lxml
```

But this is what I got:

```
PS C:\Users\foo> pip install lxml
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Real name of requirement lxml is lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.2.4.tar.gz (3.3Mb): 3.1Mb downloaded
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,     bundle=self.b
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 961, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1079, in unpack_url
    return unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, only_download)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 449, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 367, in _download_url
    chunk = resp.read(4096)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 561, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 232, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 151, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: The read operation timed out
```

I am newbie but has never had problem with installing any package.

Please am I missing anything?
Thanks in advance

Comment: lxml requires libxml2, which is no picnic to compile, alone, on Windows. I would simply grab Python(xy), which comes with lxml (and a hell of a lot of other awesome and correct stuff), and keep going. But your actual question deserves an answer. Did pip write a build folder with a log file you can read?

Comment: `lxml` is a C-based extension. Probably following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19884061/1265154) will save you time and efforts.

Comment: as for original question, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847470/pip-search-django-produces-time-out-error

Comment: try [an unofficial binary installer for lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)

Comment: i used the unofficial binary installer referenced by @J.F.Sebastian ..not because the other comments wasn't helpful but because I  **like** installers :)